# ng-repeat doesnt work when include using ng-include

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am learning to code in Angular. I am trying to perform a ng-repeat from within a file **myTable.htm** that is included in the main html file **1.html** this however doesnt work.

**1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
<div ng-app=""> 
  <div ng-include="'myTable.htm'"></div>
</div>

<p>The HTML, and AngularJS code, for this table are located in the file "myTable.htm".</p>

</body>

</html>
```

**myTable.htm**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = ["Emil", "Tobias", "Linus"];
});
</script>
</div>
```

If I add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>` to **myTable.htm** and execute **myTable.htm** then I get the values in the select box. But it doesn't fill when I execute **1.html**.

Can anyone tell me what I have done wrong or whether what I am attempting to do is possible?

Comment: Try remove `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"` from `myTable`

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed removed `ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"` from myTable, it did not work

Comment: sorry. i forgot complete it. then add it to main html file. here `1.html`

Comment: <div ng-include src=" 'myTable.htm' "></div>  ----> TRY THIS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the ng-app defined only in the first.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
```

Remove it from the **`myTable.htm`**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/smDubHCOMlsMTkscXibV?p=preview)**

Comment: I did what you mentioned. The select box doesnt appear on the screen after making the changes

Comment: @swithencolaco check the demo

Comment: i think it's better add controller `ng-controller="myCtrl"`  to main html

Comment: @HadiJeddizahed it does not make sense! controller needs to be loaded when its necessary

Comment: @PankajParkar sure go ahead :)

Comment: @Sajeetharan the demo works perfectly. However, when I copied this code to my local and execute it it gives me a blank screen and error **ReferenceError: angular is not defined**. Any idea why?

Comment: check if you have referenced the angular reference file

Comment: @Sajeetharan I dont follow _"check if you have referenced the angular reference file"_. I have copy pasted the files as is still no go.

Comment: @swithencolaco check network tab if angular reference is called https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js

Comment: also check if you have included the script.js file

Comment: @Sajeetharan It worked. The script for angular is `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>` I had to make it `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>` Thanks a lot